# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-elb

I made server structure like picture below.

[image]

I put same ssl in two different region. But still getting this error.
I have no idea to solve this problem.
Please help me....

Comment: No I want to use domain only in the frontend. And I want to call backend api with the load balancer dns. So at the first time I just added ssl in the frontend and got the error. The error was that frontend was https but I was calling backend api with http.  @Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-use the same certificate on your ALB which you used on cloudfront. If you want SSL on ALB, you need to setup new domain for it, e.g. `alb.example.com`, get SSL cert for that new domain, and deploy it on ALB:

```
Client --- (HTTPS example.com) ---> CF (SSL for example.com) ---- (HTTPS alb.example.com) ----> ALB (SSL for alb.example.com)
```